# How to create a Spring project with Hibernate and DB2 Express-C?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2

I've been trying to find out how to create a database with tables and rows with DB2 Express-C and then do things with them through Hibernate. My problem is that references on how to do something like this don't really describe exactly what to do, is incomplete, or is very unclear on the steps.

For example, I've been trying to get [this](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/03/hibernate-jpa-with-db2?page=1) sample to work, but I think it assumes that you must already have a database up (and doesn't mention how to). The problem that follows that is that tutorials show how to create databases and tables like [this one](https://youtu.be/zXmtVjIfBzQ) don't show how that database could be connected to by something like a Spring project.

Straight to the point, I'd like to find out precisely how to do the following (or better tutorials on which) with Spring + DB2 + Hibernate and what I need to do them:

1. Create a database + tables
2. Create a simple Spring + Hibernate project that connects to the created database
3. Do CRUD functions on the tables with that project

I've had basic experience doing CRUD on MySQL (with phpmyadmin) for very simple PHP and java projects, but never while using a framework and something as complex as DB2.

Comment: It should be the same as a Spring project for any other database. You just need to add the DB2 drivers to your project. The following provides those details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411844/what-is-the-db2-jdbc-driver-or-where-can-i-get-it-from

Comment: The drivers were in the installation folder (I'll edit in the fact I'm using DB2 Express-C) but I'm having difficulties getting SQL queries/statements to work properly. Something as simple as `SELECT * FROM TABLE` works, but anything longer ends up getting read as having an invalid character in the statement (SQLCODE=-7) even if the same statement/query works in DB2's CLI.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like the problem is with the queries you are writing. You should describe the actual problem, along with code and exception details if you want a relevant answer.